Editable DataGridViewComboBox column bound to data source, or how to handle CellValidating event in custom column
I have a combo box column in DataGridView bound to data source to select item from subtable, and I want the combobox to be editable (combobox with ComboBoxStyle.DropDown style). My first idea was to create custom column like this:
    public class DgvEditableComboBoxCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    {
        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
            var comboBox = DataGridView.EditingControl as ComboBox;
            if (comboBox != null)
            {
                comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DgvEditableComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    {
        public DgvEditableComboBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = new DgvEditableComboBoxCell();
        }
    }

Then initialized like this:
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            dc = new DbDataContext();
            var col = dgv.Columns["colProjID"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            col.DataSource = dc.Proj2s.OrderBy(o => o.Code);
            col.DisplayMember = "Code";
            col.ValueMember = "ID";
        }

This is working, but when I manually type something in combo box, it's discarded and value is reverted back to original value. Next, I tried to override ParseFormattedValue in custom column, but it's not even called, probably due to some validation before.
I found similar question somewhere here and managed to make it working, but without custom column and with handling events of DataGridView like this:
        private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl combo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            }
        }

        private void dgv_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            var cell = dgv.CurrentCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            if ((cell != null) && (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "colProjID"))
            {
                string code = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
                var obj = cell.Items.Cast<Proj2>().SingleOrDefault(o => o.Code == code);
                if (obj != null)
                    cell.Value = obj.ID;
            }
        }

This is working, but my question is, is it possible to handle CellValidating in scope of custom column? I don't like this solution, because it's not independent, firstly, I have to add these two handlers for each DataGridView in which I want this functionality, and secondly, I have to hardcode subitem types, column names etc in this handler. If I could do it directly in custom column, it would be independent and I can just add custom column to DataGridView and that's all.

Your idea of making a custom column is a good one and with just a couple of small tweaks we should be able to make that work.


Set the Text value from the initialFormattedValue argument in the InitializeEditingControl method.
Override the GetFormattedValue so that it's not trying to populate the cell value using an existing value in the droplist.

protected override object GetFormattedValue(
    object value,
    int rowIndex,
    ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
    TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,
    TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
    DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
{
    return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}


Notify the DataGridView that the cell is now dirty when the text changes as a result of key events.


Minimal Example
Here's the code I used to test this answer:
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records;
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Description)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;        

        // Swap out the default bound column for the custom one.var 
        indexReplace = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Selectable)].Index;
        var dropListColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx
        { 
            Name = "DropList", 
            DataPropertyName = nameof(Record.Selectable),
        };
        dropListColumn.Items.AddRange(["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"]);
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(indexReplace);
        dataGridView.Columns.Insert(indexReplace, dropListColumn);

        dataGridView.CellValidating += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Validating {e.FormattedValue}");
        };
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Records.Add(new Record
            {
                Description = $"Item {i}"
            });
        }
    }
    BindingList<Record> Records = new BindingList<Record>();        
}
class Record
{
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public string? Selectable
    {
        get => _selectable;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_selectable, value))
            {
                _selectable = value;
                Debug.WriteLine($"PropertyChanged {Selectable}");
            }
        }
    }
    string? _selectable = default;

}
class DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, IEnumerable
{
    public DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx() => CellTemplate = new DataGridViewComboBoxCellEx();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => Items.GetEnumerator();
    public void Add(object value) => Items.Add(value);
}
class DataGridViewComboBoxCellEx : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{        
    public override Type EditType => typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControlEx);
    protected override object GetFormattedValue(
        object value,
        int rowIndex,
        ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
        TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,
        TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(
        int rowIndex,
        object initialFormattedValue, 
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        if(DataGridView?.EditingControl is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControlEx comboBoxEx)
        {
            comboBoxEx.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            comboBoxEx.Text = initialFormattedValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty ;
        }
    }
}

class DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControlEx : DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl
{
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        DroppedDown = false;
        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Escape:
                _key = Keys.None;
                BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    EditingControlDataGridView?.CancelEdit();
                });
                break;
            case Keys.Return:
                _key = Keys.None;
                BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    EditingControlDataGridView?.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                });
                break;
            default:
                _key = e.KeyData;
                break;
        }
    }
    Keys _key = Keys.None;

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if (_key == Keys.None)
        {   /* G T K */
            // Text has changed programmatically
        }
        else
        {
            EditingControlDataGridView?.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e);
        BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            EditingControlDataGridView?.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        });
    }
}


Clone Make sure it works on your end.
